# Select only one group with the most recent login date

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I am trying to just get 1 group that has the max login date.

```
user_ID    Group       Login_Date
Mulan      Flower        4/4/2017
Mulan      Badminton   11/20/2015
Mulan      Flower      11/20/2015
```

My code

```
select distinct group from table t
where t.user_ID = 'Mulan'
and t.Login_Date = (select max (t2.Login_Date)
                      from table t2
                      where t.user_ID = t2.user_ID
                        and t2.Login_date <= sysdate)
```

Result

```
Flower
Badminton
```

Desired Output

```
Flower
```

Although there are 2 Flowers, I want to make sure that I am getting the Flower with the most recent Login_Date, which is 4/4/2017, and that the output should only return 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Oracle: first/last functions
with s (user_ID, grp, Login_Date) as (
select 'Mulan', 'Flower'   , to_date('4/4/2017'  , 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'Mulan', 'Badminton', to_date('11/20/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'Mulan', 'Flower'   , to_date('11/20/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual)
select
user_id,
max(grp) keep (dense_rank last order by login_date) as grp,
max(login_date) as log_date
from s
group by user_id;

USER_ GRP       LOG_DATE
----- --------- -------------------
Mulan Flower    2017-04-04 00:00:00
```

Answer to additinal question:

```
with s (user_ID, grp, Login_Date) as (
select 'Mulan', 'Flower'   , to_date('4/4/2017'  , 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'Mulan', 'Badminton', to_date('11/20/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'Mulan', 'Flower'   , to_date('11/20/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual)
select
max(grp) keep (dense_rank last order by login_date) as grp
from s
group by user_id;

GRP
---------
Flower
```

Comment: Thanks, yours worked! But quick question, I only wanted to return "GRP." Is it possible to just select max(grp) keep (dense_rank last order by login_date) as grp ? Will it give me the correct Flower?

Comment: @BFF https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4389e24e14497762cdd59d8d4d47de58 check this link

Answer (score 0):

just remove `and t2.Login_date <= sysdate` condition

```
select  group from table t
where t.user_ID = 'Mulan' -- you dont need this if user is only Mulan
and t.Login_Date = (select max (t2.Login_Date)
                      from table t2
                      where t.user_ID = t2.user_ID
                        )
```

output

```
USER_ID     GRP     LOGIN_DATE
Mulan   Flower  04-APR-17
```

or use row_number()

```
  with cte as
  (
  select t.*,row_number()over(partition by user_ID order by Login_Date desc) rn
  from table t
 ) select * from cte where rn=1
```

output

```
USER_ID     GRP     LOGIN_DATE
Mulan   Flower  04-APR-17
```

[demo link for both version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78844774462308a1576bcfe0aa600c93)

Comment: @BFF https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17900862bc01ddd22f320c1b055d84ec check this link its working fine

Comment: @BFF both version worked https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78844774462308a1576bcfe0aa600c93

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. And your sysdate might be back to the current date.

```
select distinct top 1 group from table t
where t.user_ID = 'Mulan'
and t.Login_Date = (select max (t2.Login_Date)
                      from table t2
                      where t.user_ID = t2.user_ID
                        and t2.Login_date <= sysdate)
```

OR

```
 select distinct top 1 group from table t
    where t.user_ID = 'Mulan'
    and t.Login_Date = (select max (t2.Login_Date)
                          from table t2
                          where t.user_ID = t2.user_ID
                        )
```

Comment: TOP 1 did not work for me, it gave me an error - I am using Oracle

Comment: Please add rownum = 1 in where condition.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple solution

```
  select  top 1 max(login_date),login_group  from tableName group by login_group  order 
  by COUNT(user_id) desc
```